# Flutter: Disable Slider on Click of Switch

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, slider, uiswitch

I've got a Switch and a Slider. The Button should enable and disable the Slider, so that the User cant change the Slider.

How can I accomplish this? 
Thanks for the Help.

```
               Switch(
                 value: notifyswitch,
                 onChanged: (value) {
                   setState(() {
                     notifyswitch = value;
                   });

                 },
               ),

            Center(
              child: Text(timeoutstring, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor))
            ),

            Slider(
              min: 0.0,
              max: 48,
              divisions: 24,
              value: _timeoutvalue,

              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _timeoutvalue = value;
                  timeoutstring = _timeoutvalue.toInt().toString() + "h";
                });
              },
            )
```

Comment: A solution could be, wrapping your Slider inside an AbsorbPointer that will disable clicks on that Slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Slider's `onChanged` `null` when your `Switch` value is true

```dart
Switch(
                 value: notifyswitch,
                 onChanged: (value) {
                   setState(() {
                     notifyswitch = value;
                   });

                 },
               ),

            Center(
              child: Text(timeoutstring, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor))
            ),

            Slider(
              min: 0.0,
              max: 48,
              divisions: 24,
              value: _timeoutvalue,

              onChanged: notifyswitch?null:(value) {
                setState(() {
                  _timeoutvalue = value;
                  timeoutstring = _timeoutvalue.toInt().toString() + "h";
                });
              },
            )
```